# 'URLPattern' object is not a mapping. Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add **sitemap.xml**

I followed this tutorial https://pocoz.gitbooks.io/django-v-primerah/rasshirenie-prilozheniya-blog/dobavlenie-sitemap.html

I have an error

```
'URLPattern' object is not a mapping
In template /home/alex/root_folder/projects/6_eda_parser_regru/eda_parser_regru/src/blog/templates/blog/base.html, error at line 33
...
 <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'main_list' %}"><span style="color: red">E</span>damer</a>
```

**blog/sitemaps.py** (added new file)

```
+from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
+from .models import Shop
+
+
+class ShopSitemap(Sitemap):
+    changefreq = 'weekly'
+    priority = 0.9
+
+    def items(self):
+        return Shop.objects.all()
+
+    def lastmod(self, obj):
+        return obj.publish
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from .sitemaps import ShopSitemap
from django.conf.urls import include, url

sitemaps = {
    'shops': ShopSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='main_list'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
    path('search_shop/<slug:slug>/', ProductListView.as_view(), name='search_shop'),
    path('shops/', ShopListView.as_view(), name='shop_list'),    
    path("robots.txt", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="blog/robots.txt", content_type="text/plain"),
    #url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    # NEW LINE (reason of the error)
   url(r'^sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'), 
),
```

**models.py**

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, default="Shop")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('search_shop', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: The problem is on the previous line. You are missing a `)`. It should be `path("robots.txt", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="blog/robots.txt", content_type="text/plain")),`. Then there's an extra `)` after `url(...),` that you should remove.

Comment: As an aside, you should switch back to `r'^sitemap\.xml$'`, or use `path('sitemap.xml', ...),` so that it only matches `sitemap.xml` and not `sitemap.xmlsomethingelse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you have correct count of `)` in correct places, in your `urls.py`